# Printing the function which contains if statements, Python

Tags: python-2.7, function, if-statement, printf

I am trying to print my function in Python on Visual Studio, it has a number of "if" statements within it:

```
def correction(Diff):
    if 1 <= Diff <20 : 
        print "correction 1" # is correction necessary?
    elif 20 <= Diff < 49:
        print "correction 2" # Slight turn to right
    elif 50 <= Diff < 74:
        print "correction 3" # turn to right
    elif 75 <= Diff < 100:
        print "correction 4" # 'sharp' turn to right
    elif 100 <= Diff:
        print "correction 9" # STOP
    elif -20 <= Diff < 0:
        print "correction 5" # is correction necessary?
    elif -50 <= Diff < -20:
        print "correction 6" # Slight turn to left
    elif -75 <= Diff < -50:
        print "correction 7" # turn to left
    elif -100 < Diff < -75:
        print "correction 8" # 'sharp' turn to left
    elif Diff9 <= -100:
        print "correction 9" # STOP
    else:
        print "carry on"
return correction

print (correction)
```

Diff is fully defined before the function. However when i run the code, I get this message appear in place of the print:

```
function correction at 0x073EECB0
```

I would like the function to run and print the correct statement. The hope is to transfer this code for use on videos, therefore any suggestions and help using which minimise processing power, would be great.

Comment: typo in `elif Diff9 <= -100:`. It should be `Diff9`, without 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does actually return a reference to itself.
In order to simply run the function `correction`, just invoke it like this

```
def correction(Diff):
    # code here

correction(PARAMETER)
```

Where `PARAMETER` is a value of your choice. The function itself contains print statements, so you don't need to worry about it outside that function.

Printing `correction` will "print" the function, resulting in its address in memory being displayed.

**This is how it works**

```
def correction(Diff):
    if 1 <= Diff <20 : 
        print "correction 1" # is correction necessary?
    elif 20 <= Diff < 49:
        print "correction 2" # Slight turn to right
    elif 50 <= Diff < 74:
        print "correction 3" # turn to right
    elif 75 <= Diff < 100:
        print "correction 4" # 'sharp' turn to right
    elif 100 <= Diff:
        print "correction 9" # STOP
    elif -20 <= Diff < 0:
        print "correction 5" # is correction necessary?
    elif -50 <= Diff < -20:
        print "correction 6" # Slight turn to left
    elif -75 <= Diff < -50:
        print "correction 7" # turn to left
    elif -100 < Diff < -75:
        print "correction 8" # 'sharp' turn to left
    elif Diff9 <= -100:
        print "correction 9" # STOP
    else:
        print "carry on"

correction(Diff) # Pass any integer or integer variable here
```

Removed the `return` statement which returned a reference to the function itself and changed the `print` statement to a simple invocation of `correction()`.